# in C++, how to simplify many for loops with multi-arrays?

Tags: for-loop, c++11

[image]In practice, I will come across some big loops.
for instance, I use eight arrays, like "double a[7]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6}", to loop these conditions for the eight attributes.
to achieve this goal, I have to do eight (for-if ) loops as a nested loop.

1. it is a bit ugly and hard to change. 2 even I put these arrays in the global region, there will be segmentation errors when arrays large enough.
   Do we have some structure-strategies to handle this case? thanks a lot[image]

Comment: how do you ends up with a 8 dimensional array

Comment: The better question is, why do you have 8 dimensional arrays, so we can better help you architect your code rather than deal with 8 dimensions.

Comment: Hi@Berto99, I am not sure I got your point. each array means an attribute (for example:  Mass), for which I want to set several cut points to check which mass point is the best for me.  So finally, I want to get an attribute array which defines the best conditions combination.

Comment: If you make an array of lambdas that contain the conditions that then have a function that recurses eight times the function will be really short.  I will try to make an example.

Comment: I started to make a full example of all 14 loops with your variable names but it got big and defeated the point of an example, so my example has 3 loops and variable names that are related so you can see how it works: https://onlinegdb.com/SJvvQWMfD  You could put idx and max and func into a struct and have an array of structs instead of keeping them as separate arrays but it didn't seem to help make the example clearer.

Comment: Hi JerryJeremiah! this is exactly what I want. Thank you very much!